# Вычисление строк по hashCode

Tags: java, hashcode

Поставлена такая задача.

Есть метод **Collection getStringsForHashCode(int hashCode, int length)**
На входе `hashCode` и  `length` - кол-во символов в получаемой строке.

Метод должен найти все комбинации `char`-ов у которых сумма `hashCode` равна параметру метода и кол-во этих `char`-ов должно быть равно параметру `length` у метода.

Пример:

`getStringsForHashCode(18,3)` = `{“dad”, “bbc”, “maa”, …. }`

Подскажите как такое сделать? я вообще в тупике.

Небольшие условия:

- `hashCode` считается так: `hashCode(s) = sum (s[i] * (i+1))` где `s` строка, а `i` чар строки.
- дан метод `int getInt(char c);`
- дан метод `char getChar(int c);`
- значение `int` у `char` равно от 1 до 26. То бишь `getInt('a')` = 1 и т.д.

Я честно хз как лучше решить. надо случайным образом брать чар и пытаться склеивать с другими. Или же идти от обратного: найти сумму цифр и потом по полученным цифрам найти char.

Буду очень благодарен помощи)

Comment: решение в лоб перебор с отсечением если сумма становится больше хэша

Comment: @Grundy два чара собрать не проблема. Но вот если уже 3? то тут уже проблема. Рандомно собирать строку? Проблема не в подсчете хеша и его сравнении, а как собрать чары.

Comment: Не надо собирать строку, надо перебирать числа в уравнении. Количество переменных = length, значения переменных в интервале 1..26

Comment: @Grundy Интересно. мысли на счет самой реализации есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже сказал Grundy это задача поиска целочисленных решений уравнения, лежащих в диапазоне 1..26.

```
1 * x1 + 2 * x2 + 3 * x3 + ... + n * xn = hash
```

Можно считать её разновидностью задачи о наборе суммы - какие наборы из n монет с достоинством 1..26 дадут нужную сумму. Пример на Python.

По пределам отсечения: минимальное значение, которое можно набрать из n-1 первых символов, есть `1+2+3+4+..+n-1 = n*(n-1)/2`, а максимальное - 26 умножить на это значение.

```
def getstr(hash, n, s):
    if (n==0):
        if (hash == 0):
            print(s)
        return

    for i in range(max(1, hash // n - 13 * (n-1)), min(26, (hash - (n * (n-1) //2))) // n + 1):
        getstr(hash - i * n, n - 1, chr(ord('a') + i - 1) + s)    

getstr(18, 3, "")

>>
maa
kba
ica
gda
eea
cfa
aga
jab
hbb
fcb
ddb
beb
gac
ebc
ccc
adc
dad
bbd
aae
```

[Java code](https://ideone.com/YewAAj)

```
class Ideone
{   
    public static void findStrs(int hash, int n, String s) {
    if (n==0) {
        System.out.println(s);
        return;
    }   

    int from = hash / n - 13 * (n-1);
    from = (from < 1)? 1: from;
    int to = (hash - (n * (n-1) / 2)) / n;
    to = (to > 26)? 26: to;

    for (int i = from; i<= to; i++){
        //System.out.println(i);
        findStrs(hash - i * n, n - 1, (char)(97 + i - 1) + s);   
    }
   return;
 } 
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
       findStrs(18, 3, ""); // your code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: а зачем на входе строка даётся?

Comment: Пустая строка как начальный параметр рекурсивной функции. На каждом уровне рекурсии к ней добавляется один символ, пока не соберётся полная валидная строка длиной n.  Можно сделать отдельную функцию без этого аргумента, которая уже будет вызывать рекурсивную

Comment: @Tsyklop Модифицировал пределы цикла, чтобы избавиться от лишних итераций.

Comment: На "пиджин" Джаву перевёл

Comment: откуда 13? это 26/2? что такое 97?

Comment: 13=26/2, 97 это код  'a'.

Comment: а чего именно 'a'? есть метод `getChat()`

Comment: удивительно, но это работает.

Comment: Ну у меня Java нет, и методов я не знаю ;) Кроме того, from и to надо с помощью max/min считать, чтобы короче и понятнее было

Answer (score 0):

Для оптимизации перебора можно ограничить максимальное значение элемента строки. Строка `"ааа"` уже генерирует `hash = 1+2+3 = 6`. И для третьего элемента нет смысла добавлять что то больше `(18-1-2)/3 = 5` т.е. `"е"`. Перебор для больших `lenght` и малых `hash` будет существенно сокращен.
 Например `getStringsForHashCode(175, 18)` даст следующую маску максимальных значений элементов, шестьдесят возможных вариантов и всего пять решений:

```
[5, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
eaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
cbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
acaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
babaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Comment: Один момент - хеш вычисляется не просто `1+2+3` а по формуле `sum (s[i] * (i+1))` где `s` строка, а `i` чар строки.

Comment: конечно, это пример для строки `"aaa"`  `(a=1)*1 + (a=1)*2 + (a=1)*3 = 6`, соответственно  `(a=1)*1 + (a=1)*2 + (е=5)*3 = 18`, или я неверно понял как вычислять hash?

Comment: Так поняли. `(18-1-2)/3 = 5` что из этого 1, 2 и 3?

Comment: 1 и 2 это минимальные значения слогаемых от первого и второго элемента строки, а 3 - коэффициент для третьего. Т.е. максимальное значение для n-ого элемента можно вычислить как целую часть от выражения (hash - (минимальная сумма в хэше всех элементов строки кроме n)) / n

Comment: так то хорошо, но вот как их вычислять?

Comment: маска максимальных значений для элементов: `max[i] = (int) (hash - (( 1.0 * length / 2 + 0.5) * length - i - 1)) / (i + 1);`  Этот подход не панацея, но когда минимальный хэш близок к искомому - хорош работает. У строки с 18 элементами миниальный хэш 1+2+3...+18 = 171